# How to use \valign?

Tags: tex-core

I just bumped into a interesting command called `\valign`. It seems to be the sister of `\halign`, but the TeXbook seems to be rather shy on explaining its use. As is the TeX by Topic. They only mention it swaps the meaning of rows and columns in its use when compared to `\halign`. But given the following example:

```
\valign{&#\cr
How  & is\cr
this & supposed\cr
to   & work?\cr
}
\bye
```

the produced box is overfull; the second column starts only after the right margin!

So my question is: how is it supposed to be used; how can you change the start of the second (or third) column so it doesn't go out of the page? Also if you have some usage examples somewhere, that'd be great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is that each entry is typeset in internal vertical mode, which implies that when you feed it horizontal mode material, as you have done, you get that material typeset as paragraphs, resulting in boxes of width `\hsize`. Hence the overfull you have noticed. Here is a slightly improved version of your example:

```
\valign{&\vfil\vbox{\parindent=0pt\hsize=20mm #}\vfil\cr
How  & is is is is is is is is is is is is is\cr
this & supposed\cr
to to to to to to to to to to to to to to to to  & work?\cr
}
\bye
```

As for a real-life useful example, I haven't got one (other than the single row example `\valign{\vfil#\vfil\cr…}` mentioned in the TeX book). Maybe someone else will have one.

Comment: No one said that _every_ primitive was useful: `\outer` is the classic example.

Comment: I did once find a good use case for \valign. For the 1990 TUG meeting in Cork I produced a pocket diary, which contained a tabular calendar for the year. Typesetting the blocks of months with rows labelled with the days of the week was done quite easily with \valign.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a modification of Herbert's example that places each entry in an `\hbox` of natural width and then inserts `\hfil` between all of the columns by redefining `\cr`.

```
\def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\hfil}}
\valign{&\hbox{\strut#}\crcr
badness  & box& boxmaxdepth& cleaders& dp& everyhbox\cr
everyvbox& hbadness& hbox& hfuzz& hrule& ht& lastbox\cr
leaders& overfullrule& prevdepth& setbox& unhbox& unhcopy& unvbox\cr
unvcopy& vbadness& vbox& vfuzz& vrule& vsplit& vtop\cr
wd& xleaders\cr}
\unskip
\bye
```

Note the final `\crcr` that ends the alignment preamble and the `\unskip` that follows. The `\unskip` could be removed and the final `\cr` changed to a `\crcr`.

That same trick could be used to stick a fixed amount of space between columns (note that `\tabskip` glue goes between rows here) or the not-very-well-known `\hbox spread` construct can be used. This inserts an extra em of space between columns.

```
\valign{&\hbox spread1em{\strut#\hfil}\cr
badness  & box& boxmaxdepth& cleaders& dp& everyhbox\cr
everyvbox& hbadness& hbox& hfuzz& hrule& ht& lastbox\cr
leaders& overfullrule& prevdepth& setbox& unhbox& unhcopy& unvbox\cr
unvcopy& vbadness& vbox& vfuzz& vrule& vsplit& vtop\cr
wd& xleaders\cr}
\bye
```

It's worth pointing out that by starting the alignment with a `&`, it causes the entire preamble to be repeated.

Answer (score 7):

An example from David Bausum's book

```
\valign{&\hbox to 1in{\vrule height9pt depth3pt width0pt#\hfil}\vfil\cr
badness  & box& boxmaxdepth& cleaders& dp& everyhbox\cr
everyvbox& hbadness& hbox& hfuzz& hrule& ht& lastbox\cr
leaders& overfullrule& prevdepth& setbox& unhbox& unhcopy& unvbox\cr
unvcopy& vbadness& vbox& vfuzz& vrule& vsplit& vtop\cr
wd& xleaders\cr}
\bye
```

Comment: That's a good example. I was a little confused by the use of the `\vrule` at first, but it's basically a .5pt shifted `\strut`.