# Define a table one column at a time instead of one row at a time

Tags: tables, columns

Is there a way to define a table like so?

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    column 1, row 1 \\
    column 1, row 2 \\
    column 1, row 3 \\
    column 1, row 4 \\
    column 1, row 5 \\ &&
    column 2, row 1 \\
    column 2, row 2 \\
    column 2, row 3 \\
    column 2, row 4 \\
    column 2, row 5 \\
\end{tabular}
```

I'm flexible as to how it's done, I would just like to be able to define a whole column at a time (as each column's entries are highly inter-related, and not as much from row to row).

Comment: The `tabular` environment uses the plainTeX `\halign` primitive internally which needs the row-by-row format. This can't be changed. One funny idea would be to turn every cell 90degrees and then the whole table 90degr backwards, making effectively rows to columns and vice versa. However, then the cell alignment (`c`, `l`, `r`, ..) would not work as usual of course.

Comment: @Martin, Nate: \halign's counterpart is \valign which switches cols to rows, there's some rather nice examples of its use here in this site.

Comment: @morbusg: I know `\valign` but you can't just say `{\let\halign\valign\begin{tabular}{..} ..`, can you?

Comment: @Martin: oh, right, I didn't think quite that far. Merely, your description rang a bell. :-)

Comment: It's a shame there's no `tabularv` that uses `\valign`... as I think that's what I really wanted (and I am not enough of a TeX guru to be able to create)

Comment: One possible approach is to collect the whole tabular in some data structure, and read the rows one by one afterwards, rather than the columns.

Comment: @Bruno: Yes, but how does one go about making a list variable in TeX?

Comment: @Nate: you can for instance `\usepackage{expl3}` and use the sequence data type with commands such as `\seq_new:N` or `\seq_put_left:Nn`. To collect cell contents, you can try to use the `collcell` package. A quite different approach would be to typeset each cell in a box of its own, reorder boxes, and "unbox" them. It depends on whether you need verbatim content to be allowed or not.

Comment: I tried the three proposed methods. All of them work. Great examples. But, with the second method, the spaces betwen words are compressed. I added a title and text between the tables and observed that there aren't enough vertical space between tables and paragraphs. Probably an incorrect apreciation of mine, but the visual appearance is of a table too close to the text. Also, with the second method, the paragraphs does not wraps at the margin.

Comment: @djnavas: Such feedback, if it is not an answer by itself, should be posted as comment. Unfortunately new users can add comments to any post and question only after you reached 50rep points. I converted your post to a comment now for you. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @djnavas: Sorry, I had forgotten to put `\ExplSyntaxOff` to restore spaces to teir normal (non-ignored) behaviour. For line breaks, you should typically load the `array` package, and replace the `cccc` preamble by something containing `p{<dimen>}` (see array documentation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use two tabulars ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c}
    column 1, row 1 \\
    column 1, row 2 \\
    column 1, row 3 \\
    column 1, row 4 \\
    column 1, row 5 \\
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|}
    column 2, row 1 \\
    column 2, row 2 \\
    column 2, row 3 \\
    column 2, row 4 \\
    column 2, row 5 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shame on me for not thinking of the obvious thing ;^).  Obviously, these are two separate tables, so is there any way to set equal rubber column widths, like with `tabularx`'s `X`?  Or is the only option to set explicit widths with `p{}`?

Comment: Actually, while I'm at it - is there a way to balance the number of rows across tables?  Not all of my columns have the same number of rows, but (obviously) the `\hline`s at the bottom all need to line up.

Comment: @Nate: then use `[b]` instead of `[t]` to align the tabulars at the bottom.

Comment: Ah, I guess I wasn't specific enough - I meant that I wanted both the top and the bottom to line up.  I.e., some way to say "make these two tables the same height".  For now it's not that big of a deal... I just put in filler.

Answer (score 4):

The code below defines a `vtab` environment which reads its body (thanks to the `environ` package) and splits it into columns, and cells (using some LaTeX3 code), then puts it back together in rows rather than columns, and places its two arguments before and after the result. It is used as

```
\begin{vtab}{\begin{tabular}{cccc}}{\end{tabular}}
a\\b\\c\\d&
e\\f&
g\\h\\i&
j\\k\\l\\m\\n\\o
\end{vtab}
```

There are some comments in the code below, don't hesitate to ask. Earlier, I forgot the `\ExplSyntaxOff` line, which restores the normal TeX behaviour (spaces not ignored).

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% \NewEnviron defines |\begin{vtab}| to grab until |\end{vtab}|
% and store the result in |\BODY|. Then two steps.
% (1) Split |\BODY| into cells, storing them in a property list.
% (2) Read the property list in a different order, building the
% body of the tabular as we go.
% (3) Typesetting the tabular.
%
\NewEnviron { vtab } [2]
  {
    \TV_read:V \BODY
    \TV_build:
    \tl_put_left:Nn \l_TV_result_tl { #1 }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_TV_result_tl { #2 }
    \tl_use:N \l_TV_result_tl
  }

% We need some variables.
\int_new:N \l_TV_col_int
\int_new:N \l_TV_row_int
\int_new:N \l_TV_max_row_int
\prop_new:N \l_TV_cells_prop
\tl_new:N \l_TV_result_tl
\tl_new:N \l_TV_row_tl
\tl_new:N \l_TV_cell_tl

% Generic function to split a list with items delimited by a given token
% (in our application, either & or \\) and apply the third argument to
% each item that was found: this third argument will receive the item as
% |#1|. Used as |\TV_map_inline:nnn {\\} {a\\b\\c} {do #1}|.
%
% It is slightly tricky to get nesting to work (see e.g., explanations
% for |\clist_map_inline:nn| in |l3clist.dtx|).
%
\int_new:N \g_TV_map_inline_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \TV_map_inline:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#2}
      {
        \cs_gset_eq:cN
          {TV_map_inline_\int_use:N \g_TV_map_inline_int :w}
          \TV_map_inline_aux:w
        \int_gincr:N \g_TV_map_inline_int
        %
        \cs_gset:Npn \TV_map_inline_aux:w ##1 #1 
          {
            \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {##1}
            #3
            \TV_map_inline_aux:w
          }
        \TV_map_inline_aux:w #2 #1 \q_recursion_tail #1 \q_recursion_stop
        %
        \int_decr:N \g_TV_map_inline_int
        \cs_gset_eq:Nc
          \TV_map_inline_aux:w
          {TV_map_inline_\int_use:N \g_TV_map_inline_int :w}
      }
  }

% We split into columns first |&|, then rows |\\|. While doing this,
% we keep track of the index of the row and column, and what the
% highest row number is (this will be the number of rows in the
% resulting tabular). The cell's content is stored as the property
% "row,column" in |\l_TV_cells_prop|.
%
\cs_new:Npn \TV_read:n #1
  {
    \int_zero:N \l_TV_col_int
    \int_zero:N \l_TV_max_row_int
    \TV_map_inline:nnn {&} {#1}
      {
        \int_incr:N \l_TV_col_int
        \int_zero:N \l_TV_row_int
        \TV_map_inline:nnn {\\} {##1}
          {
            \int_incr:N \l_TV_row_int
            \exp_args:NNx \prop_put:Nnn \l_TV_cells_prop
              { \int_use:N \l_TV_row_int , \int_use:N \l_TV_col_int }
              { ####1 }
          }
        \int_compare:nT { \l_TV_row_int > \l_TV_max_row_int }
          { \int_set_eq:NN \l_TV_max_row_int \l_TV_row_int }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \TV_read:n {V}

% To build, loop for |##1| from 1 to the number of rows,
% and for |####1| from 1 to the number of columns, and extract
% the relevant cell, then place it in the relevant row.
% The funny |\use_none:n| business removes the first |&| from
% each row as it is added to the result.
\cs_new:Npn \TV_build:
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_TV_result_tl 
    \prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn {1} {1} { \l_TV_max_row_int }
      {
        \tl_clear:N \l_TV_row_tl
        \prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn {1} {1} { \l_TV_col_int }
          {
            \prop_pop:NnNF \l_TV_cells_prop { ##1 , ####1 } \l_TV_cell_tl
              { \tl_clear:N \l_TV_cell_tl }
            \tl_put_right:Nx \l_TV_row_tl { & \exp_not:V \l_TV_cell_tl }
          }
        \exp_args:NNf \tl_put_right:Nn \l_TV_result_tl
          { \exp_after:wN \use_none:n \l_TV_row_tl \\ }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff % [EDIT: added that line]
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{vtab}{\begin{tabular}{cccc}}{\end{tabular}}
a\\b\\c\\d&
e\\f&
g\\h\\i&
j\\k\\l\\m\\n\\o
\end{vtab}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a plain-tex version using `\valign`, adapted from [TH.'s awesome answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/how-to-use-valign/12166#12166).

```
\valign{&\hbox spread1em{\strut#\hfil}\cr
column 1, row 1 & column 1, row 2 & column 1, row 3 & column 1, row 4 \cr
column 2, row 1 & column 2, row 2 & column 2, row 3 & column 2, row 4 \cr}
\bye
```

Comment: Do you think that this could be used as a basis for a tabular-like environment? (I tried, but failed)

Comment: @morbusg - Now, how do you include borders as  nice as the ones in `tabular`?  I couldn't get it to do `\hline`s at all.

Comment: @Bruno: I'm sorry to say I haven't yet got that far that I'd understand anything about LaTeX (I am still learning the primitives and plain-format). I did take a look at `\def\tabular` in `latex.ltx`, but I didn't really understand anything I saw. (lots and lots of `@`'s `:-)`)

Comment: @Nate: by borders do you mean rules around the whole construct? If so, you can just stuff the `\valign` inside a `\fbox`. (`\fbox{\valign{...}}`)

Comment: @morbusg: I understand. Tabulars in LaTeX are quite complicated. I'll ask "GL" (author of the tabu package, vary talkative on comp.text.tex) if he plans to do anything like that.

Comment: @morbusg: No - I mean any kind of border anywhere on any cell.  If I wanted to make a table with interior lines, say one between the first and second lines, and one between the columns, that's easy to do using `tabular`.  And I haven't a clue how one would do that here.

Comment: @morbusg: thank you for the update. In order to give functionalities similar to tabular, we would need to be able to control the alignment: here it is top-left aligned, is it possible to center it (say, horizontally)? I'm asking because I failed to do it.

Comment: @Bruno: I've been investigating solutions to your question for a while now, but I realize I'm way out of my league with LaTeX (I don't exactly know what makes things behave so differently; it's as if `\vbox`es and `\hbox`es act differently under LaTeX.) I'll just delete the LaTeX part.

Comment: @morbusg: LaTeX does not change `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\halign` and `\valign`, so things should work in the same way for LaTeX and plain TeX. Even in plain TeX I don't know how to get horizontally centered cells in a `\valign`.