# What is the purpose of \crcr in an \halign preamble?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, plain-tex

I know that the point of `\crcr` is to be a kind of "backup `\cr`" in `\halign`/`\valign`, in that it only adds a `\cr` if it wouldn't result in two in a row.  Nonetheless it seems to find its way into the `\halign` preamble, where it seems merely like a slightly-longer version of `\cr`.  For example, the plain Tex definition of `\matrix`:

```
*\show\matrix
> \matrix=macro:
#1->\null \,\vcenter {%
  \normalbaselines \m@th \ialign {%
    \hfil $##$\hfil &&\quad \hfil $##$\hfil \crcr
    \mathstrut \crcr
    \noalign {\kern -\baselineskip }%
    #1\crcr 
    \mathstrut \crcr
    \noalign {\kern -\baselineskip }%
  }%
}\,.
```

(I have added some formatting).  I don't get why the preamble would end in `\crcr` when `\cr` works just as well, is the *only* option mentioned by the TeXbook, and when `\crcr` doesn't seem to function as a backup `\cr` in this case.  Now, the *third* `\crcr` does have that particular function here, but in the very simple alignment

```
\halign{#\crcr x}
```

you will get a "Missing `\cr` inserted" error nonetheless.  I have seen this idiom elsewhere so I assume it has *some* reason but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: apart from the `#1\crcr ` one I think they could all be `\cr` with no change in behaviour.

Comment: I think it is so you can do this: `\matrix{a\cr b}` and/or this: `\matrix{a\cr b\cr}` (unless that's what you meant by "backup `\cr`").

Comment: @morbusg no that's what the `#1\crcr` one does the others are totally equivalent to `\cr` I think it is just Knuth's style to use crcr everywhere in macro definitions, presumably to save remembering, and to leave `\cr` for use in table bodies in the document

Comment: @David, Ah, I see, thanks. Ryan: One thing that I remember used on this site, is that it leaves the redefinition of `\cr` open to the user, at least.

Comment: @morbusg I think you nailed it.

Comment: Oh, good point. So this is something that would be covered in latex by naming it something internal. You can upgrade that to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One explanation of the use of `\crcr` could be that it leaves redefinition of `\cr` open to the user.

An example of this is in @TH.’s answer on [How to use \valign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/how-to-use-valign/12166#12166) where he redefines `\cr` to mean

```
\def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\hfil}}
```

so one gets glue between columns in `\valign`. I think it is very clever.